# Reading and playing audio file

Tags: java, android, audio

I'm having some trouble with reading and playing certain audio clips on Android 2.0.1 (Motorola Droid A855). Below is the code segment that I use. It works fine for some files, but for other files it just doesn't exit the while loop. I have tried checking

```
InputStream.available()
```

method but with no luck. I even printed out the number of bytes it reads properly before getting stuck. It seems that it gets stuck in the loop at the last round of read (have less than < 512 bytes left), and doesn't exit the loop.

```
    int sampleFreq = 44100;
    int minBufferSize = AudioTrack.getMinBufferSize(sampleFreq, AudioFormat.CHANNEL_IN_STEREO, AudioFormat.ENCODING_PCM_16BIT);
    int bufferSize = 512;
    AudioTrack at = new AudioTrack(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC, sampleFreq, AudioFormat.CHANNEL_IN_STEREO, AudioFormat.ENCODING_PCM_16BIT, minBufferSize, AudioTrack.MODE_STREAM);


    InputStream input;
    try {
        File fileID=new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(),resourceID);
        input = new FileInputStream( fileID);
        int filesize=(int)fileID.length();
        int i=0,byteread=0;     
        byte[] s = new byte[bufferSize];

        at.play();
        while((i = input.read(s, 0, bufferSize))>-1){
             at.write(s, 0, i);
             //at.flush(); 
             byteread+=i;
             Log.i(TAG,"playing audio "+byteread+"\t"+filesize);
        }

        at.stop();  
        at.release();
        input.close();


    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        // TODO
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Audio files are around 1-2MB in size and are in **wav** format. Following is an example of the logging-

```
> : playing audio 1057280   1058474
> : playing audio 1057792   1058474
> : playing audio 1058304   1058474
```

Any idea why this is happening as it runs perfectly for some of the audio files.

Comment: How does it get stuck - does it repeatedly get an unexpected return value, or does it block?

Comment: It just blocks I guess as it doesn't exit the while loop (where I do/call other stuffs). My main question would be why doesn't it finish reading the whole file. For the files that work, I see the code reading the whole file (e.g., bytesread = filesize)

Comment: That's an invalid assumption, not an answer to my query.  Blocking would mean that the read() method never returns.  But it could well be returning a value that wouldn't cause your loop to exit.  Your log call should show what is happening.

Comment: I see the following log-- obtainBuffer timed out (is the CPU pegged?)

Comment: Take out the at.write() line so you are just discarding the data, and just see what buffer sizes you get by charging through the file only reading.  Perhaps you get an oddball return value, and calling write with that size isn't legitimate.  You should probably also (temporarily) move your size logging call before your write attempt, so you know what size you will be calling write() with *before* you actually call it.

Comment: Great! just did what you asked. So the last write is the problem, without the write function it works fine (exits the loop). I then checked the amount of reads taking place before write too. Here are the logs for a sample file- I/AudioFingerprint(17545): before write 881152 882074 512
05-01 16:20:21.418:  after write 881664 882074 512
05-01 16:20:21.418:  before write 881664 882074 410. It does read the right amount remaining for the last round but fails to write it for some reason and as result gets stuck.

Comment: What is the last size you call write() with?  If it's zero, you probably shouldn't do that.  If it's some positive number much smaller than the minimum buffer size, having that be invalid would seem like a bit of a platform bug, but perhaps you could fix it by zero-padding out to the minimum buffer size and delivering that.

Comment: A last size that's not an integral multiple of a stereo sample (ie, 2x16 bits = 4 bytes) could be bad too.

Comment: The last write size is 410 bytes (<512 bytes but still significant I believe)

Comment: Try padding it out to the minimum buffer size.  And I think you should be trying to obtain minimum buffer size worth of data in each read, NOT your 512 bytes.

Comment: OK, just cross-checked the issue of file size. And yes for all the working files, the file size is an integral multiple of 4 bytes. The ones that are not an integral multiple of 4 bytes are causing the problem. Thanks dude ...I have been trying to figure this out for a day as it works perfectly on the newer androids (android >=4)

Comment: Seems like you either have a corrupted (crudely truncated?) .wav file, or else you are assuming the sample start from the beginning of the file, treating a non-multiple-of-four-length header as sample data, and so not only generating some initial grunge but possibly swapping the stereo channels as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure your call to write() always delivers a byte size which is an integral number of samples.

For your 16 bit stereo mode, that should be an integral multiple of 4 bytes.

Additionally, at least before the final write, for stutter-free operation you should really respect the minimum buffer size of the audio subsystem and deliver at least that much data in each call to the audio write method.

If your source data is a .wav file, make sure you actually skip the header and read samples only starting from a valid payload chunk.